# Grafana Variable issue

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have created a variable name "app" by using query options

`label_values(app_name)`,

so now when i add  `label_values(app_name)` 
i get a all the apps which are with associated with this `app_name` variable.  I have 15 apps under this variable say

`apple , banana , citrus , android`

now i just need `citrus` to be displayed and others should not. So any suggestions how to use variables in grafana and data source is prometheus.

Example in below image i just need `0.25` to be displayed instead of `0
0.01
0.05
0.25
0.5
0.75
0.9
0.99
1`
[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grafana variables works the same way with the all the datasources, you can just take a look here http://docs.grafana.org/reference/templating/

When you have created a variable you can use it like this in your prometheus requests:

```
node_cpu{instance=$variable}
```

Grafana should show your variable at the top of the dashboard and when you select the instance you want, should update the panels.